# Horizontal image Slider glitching when page loads

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, safari, slider

I have a horizontal slider in react , when it loads the images move around and then stop and behave normally only when loading , The images are different widths when i make the images same width the error stops . This behavior only happens in saffari browser , in chrome its working fine

```
 {GalleryData.map((item: any, index: number) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className={`flex justify-center h-full items-start flex-col md:mr-4 `}
          >
            {item.artistName ? (
              <Link
                href={{
                  pathname: item.workUrl,
                  query: { artist: item.artistName, title: item.category, artistslug: item.artistUrl },
                }}
                className={`md:h-[calc(100%-20px)] ${SetImageWidth(
                  item.Landscape
                )} relative overflow-hidden Detail-Link transition-all duration-300 w-full md:w-auto`}
              >
                {imagesLoaded &&
                   <Image
                   src={item.blurDataURL}
                  data-srcset={`${item.srcSet}`}
                  alt=""
                  width={item.Landscape ? 1200 : 900}
                  height={item.Landscape ? 675 : 1238}
                  style={{ maxWidth: 'none', width: 'auto', height: '100%' }}
                  className={`lazyload ${
                  item.Landscape ? 'md:object-fill' : 'md:object-fill'
                   } object-contain md:block hidden ${
                   imagesLoaded ? 'fade-in' : 'opacity-0'
                   } transition-opacity duration-500`}
                   
                 />
                }
                
              </Link>
            ) : (
              <Link
                href={item.workUrl}
                className={`w-auto md:h-[calc(100%-20px)] ${SetImageWidth(
                  item.Landscape
                )} relative overflow-hidden Detail-Link transition-all duration-300`}
              >
                {item.URL &&
                  <img
                    src={item.blurDataURL}
                    alt=""
                    data-srcset={`${item.srcSet}`}
                    style={{ maxWidth: 'none', width: 'auto', height: '100%' }}
                    className={`lazyload ${item.Landscape ? 'md:object-fill' : 'md:object-fill'} object-contain transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out md:block hidden`}
                  />
                }
                {item.URL &&
                  <img
                    src={item.blurDataURL}
                    alt=""
                    className="lazyload w-full h-full md:hidden block"
                    style={{ width: '100%', height: 'auto' }}
                    data-srcset={`${item.srcSet}`}
                  />
                }
              </Link>
            )}
```

So i want it to display the images of diffrent sizes but its glitching , when i put the same width on the image it works but i want each image to be its width of auto

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).